# How to use some slides for display and other for handout

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I have a large beamer presentation and I want some slides to show and others for a handout that I can upload. I figured out a very rudimentary way, but I'm sure that it is possible to do in a better way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\verpres}{display}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\verpres}{print}}
  {% True case
    \input{file1.tex}
    \input{file2.tex} \pause
    \input{file3.tex} \pause
  }
  {% false case
    \input{file1.tex}
    \input{file3.tex} \pause
  }  
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the logical commands documented in the beamer manual for different modes, such as '\only<presentation>' and '\only<handout>'?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! This is a much better solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.